# Web3.js 1.2 invocation smart contract method and can not return correct result

Tags: geth, remix

When I invoke the smart contract deployed, I don't get the correct result!

I have googled, but can not fine any help.

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
contract LYQFirst{
function userRegister() public payable returns(string memory)
{
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

and my web3.js version is 1.2 and the web3.js code is as follows:

```
    var Web3 = require('web3');

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {

  console.log("Hello World"); 
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {

  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider    ("http://localhost:8545"));
    }
      var contract1 = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "userRegister",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
    }
],"0xd62f32665ac53749ded4a38d984d70f180d2908a");

 contract1.methods.userRegister().send  
  ({from: "0x18244fbf3b47175cd6b4a1183a476c9e70cb7368",gas:200000}).then        (function(error,result){
    
 console.log(error);
 console.log("result="+result);
 });
```

The geth including followings modules and their versions.

modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0.

I installed web3.js 1.2 by `npm install web3` for interacting with geth.

The result I got from web3 code is as following:

```
{ blockHash:
   '0x4865c3845d88d7022962833b663ed298f1a0e5b2e7e4905c7b0c968972790174',
 blockNumber: 3186,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21847,
  from: '0x18244fbf3b47175cd6b4a1183a476c9e70cb7368',
  gasUsed: 21847,
 logsBloom:
   '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
 root:
  '0x0141214730cebc516bf7036c8b36a24af0a29dbc11ef8ef9daf05448bb84eec5',
  to: '0xd62f32665ac53749ded4a38d984d70f180d2908a',
  transactionHash:
   '0x804d4751eb7ab6b5f31f709dafc98bfa0b7433758ac9b0d58348b34173f832b8',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  events: {} }
result=undefined
<<< Process finished (PID=9824). (Exit code 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get return value if it's a transaction (send, not call) from Javascript. Transactions return transaction receipt, and that's what you got.

If you need the value, store it an a public storage variable and call it's getter function.

Comment: The geth including followings modules and their versions. modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0.  I installed web3.js 1.2 .  if they are matched?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused.